# flutter/dart: How to add SVG image to container background

Tags: flutter, dart

I am adding **SVG** image to container background but it dos not accept so how i can add **SVG** image to Container background and I am trying in the following way but it dos not work

```
 Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: SvgPicture.asset("assets/bg/image.svg"),
              ),
            ),
),
```

Comment: You can use the SvgPicture.asset() widget to load an SVG image from your assets folder.

Comment: boxdecoration accept imageProvider when is pass SvgPicture.asset() it show the error that the argument type svg cannot be assigned to the parameter type ImageProvider

Comment: I don't think that would possible, try stack to set your svg as background.

Comment: @MohamedElgazar@eamirho3ein thanks for your comments and I have used stack